# JDBC connection in jsp to MySQL in bluemix hangs the page

Tags: jsp, jdbc, ibm-cloud

index.html or any ordinary jsp in myblumix.net are working fine, but while putting JDBC code in JSP, the page does not respond.
Here is my jSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page  import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://155.247.251:3307/dB-Name","user-name","password");

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from orgmaster");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Bluemix test</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
%>
<h1>JSP in blue mix <%= rs.getString(2) %></h1>
<%
}
con.close();
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you paste logs? 'cf logs appname --recent'

Comment: Problem was hereConnection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://155.247.251:3307/dB-Name","user-name","password"); It should be Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc :mysql://192.155.247.251:3307/dB-Name","user-name","password");. I had left a number in IP

Comment: Thanks Ram, It is solved

Comment: As this was caused by a typographical error (omitting part of the IP address), I don't see that this question would be of any help to others, so I'm voting to put this on hold.

Answer (score 0):

even though supported by Java liberty runtime on bluemix, hardcoding DB connection parameters on JSP code is discouraged.
Using VCAP_SERVICES is strongly recommended, as documented in bluemix tutorials.
Following an example of VCAP_SERVICES parsing and using,

```
import com.ibm.nosql.json.api.*; 
  import com.ibm.nosql.json.util.*;

  // Block for parsing VCAP SERVICES
  String VCAP_SERVICES = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
  BasicDBObject sqldb;
  BasicDBObject credentials;
  String databaseUrl;
  if (VCAP_SERVICES != null) {
        BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(VCAP_SERVICES);
        String thekey = null;
        Set<String> keys = obj.keySet();
        for (String eachkey : keys)
               if (eachkey.toUpperCase().contains("SQLDB"))
                              thekey = eachkey;
              }
        }
         BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList) obj.get(thekey);
         sqldb = (BasicDBObject) list.get("0");
         credentials = (BasicDBObject) sqldb.get("credentials");
         databaseUrl = credentials.get("jdbcurl");
   }
   else {
        // we are not executing inside bluemix, use a local DB
        databaseUrl = "jdbc:db2://" + databaseHost + ":" + port + "/" + databaseName;       
   }
```

You can find a complete tutorial about getting VCAP_SERVICES here
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html
at the paragraph
"Parse VCAP_SERVICES"